# React Native : Assigning props value to state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can some one tell me how I can assign a value from props to a value in state ?

For example the below component gets several values from parent component as props.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';



export default class Logitem extends Component {

  constructor(props)  {
    super(props);
    const { logstringdate, bmi, weight, logdate } = this.props;
  }

  state = {
    selecteddate: '',
    selectedweight: ''

  }

onWeightClick = () => {
  this.setState({ selecteddate: this.props.logdate });
  console.log('Value in props==>'+this.props.logdate);
  console.log('The selecteddate in the state ==> '+ this.state.selecteddate);
}


render() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
              <View style={styles.headerContentStyle}>
                    <Text>{this.props.logstringdate}</Text>
                    <Text>{this.props.bmi}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>
                    <Text onPress={this.onWeightClick}>{this.props.weight}</Text>
              </View>
    </View>
  );

}
};

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2},
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop:10,
  },
  thumbnailContainerStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row'

  },
  headerContentStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-around'
  },
};
```

The props passed to this `LogItem` component are `logstringdate, bmi, weight, logdate`.

I am setting the state (`selecteddate`) upon press event.

The event is getting triggered but for some reason `this.setState` is not working (i.e not assigning the value from the state to the props).

I have verified that the props is indeed passed and it is not null.

My output

[image]

Comment: Make usre to bind `onWeightClick ` inside constructor and move `this.state` inside constructor , and pass callback function to `onWeightClick` as setState is asynchronous

Comment: @Aaqib : I am not sure the issue is with the handler. Thehandler is getting invoked and also " = () =>" is pretty much equivalent (afaik) to bind

Comment: There is no need to explicit `bind` arrow functions, they use the lexical scope for the `this` key word (which is the class instance).

Comment: I am still living in old world , did not realise its an arrow function !

Answer (score 4):

Well that because `setState` is asynchronous. it doesn't really updating the state immediately.
there is  a second argument for `setState` which is a callback that get invoked right after the state been set.

```
  onWeightClick = () => {
    this.setState({ selecteddate: this.props.logdate }, () => {

      console.log('Value in props==>' + this.props.logdate);
      console.log('The selecteddate in the state ==> ' + this.state.selecteddate);
    });
  }
```